# Select single value but sort on another value that occurs in the same column

Tags: mysql

This is the query I am using which works fine but I want the result set to be sorted alphabetically on a second value occurring in the same column.

```
SELECT userid 
FROM my_table 
WHERE value = $corrected_gradyear
and attributeid = 4
```

Table setup is like this

```
attributeid userid value
3           1231   maidenname
2           1231   lastname
4           1231   1980
5           1231   address
8           1231   phone
9           1231   email
3           5      maidenname
2           5      lastname
4           5      1978
5           5      address
8           5      phone
9           5      email
```

I just want the userid ids but I want them to be sorted alphabetically by attributeid 3 (maiden name).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what are you want?

```
select t1.userid,t1.value as year,t2.value as maidenname from my_table t1
join my_table t2 on t2.userid = t1.userid and t2.attributeid=3
where t1.attributeid=4
order by t1.value,t2.value
```

Comment: Did not work for me... don't I need something like order by value where attribute id = 3

Comment: Show me what do you want to select from your topic table with order (print me result).

Comment: I want to select all of the userids where the grad year is the same and then order the results by the value maidenname (attributeid 3).

Comment: check my answer and work with order ASC, DESC. Is it what are you need? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e2f/3/0 sqlfiddle to play with params.

Comment: Does my actual table name go where tstab is?

Comment: No errors for the query you sent but it selected all of the userids, not just from one particular year as it should. Also it did not seem to sort.

Comment: If you want only one year, you need to add `t1.value = '1980'` in your `where` clause. If you don't set year - you'll get all of your ID's. Try to select full my query and you see order by year and than alphabetic order by maidenname.

Answer (score 0):

That is just a horrible table.

I guess what you have to do is:

```
SELECT VALUE as MaidenName
FROM my_table WHERE attributeID = 3
AND UserID IN 
(SELECT userid 
   FROM my_table 
   WHERE value = $corrected_gradyear
   and attributeid = 4)
ORDER BY MaidenName
```

Comment: This does not work either, I think the userid is not there in the result set. My While loop access the result set using this code: $Rowone[userid]

Comment: I applied my answer above to the other sqlfiddle referenced: [it works.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e2f/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tUsers.userid 
FROM my_table tUsers
INNER JOIN my_table tMaidenNames ON tMaidenNames.userid = tUsers.userid AND tMaidenNames.attributeid = 3
WHERE tUsers.value = $corrected_gradyear
AND tUsers.attributeid = 4
ORDER BY tMaidenNames.value ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dc63/2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN  attributeid = 4 THEN value END) corrected_grad_year
     , MAX(CASE WHEN  attributeid = 3 THEN value END) maidenname 
  FROM eav_hell 
 GROUP 
    BY userid
 ORDER
    BY whatever;
```